# How to structure multiple Prism Xamarin.Forms apps with shared modules

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am now starting a project and I would like to use prism modules. 
Imagine this scenario:

- App1 (e.g. Uber App)
- App2 (e.g. Uber Driver App)
- AuthenticationModule

**How should the project be structured?**

- It is possible to have 3 separate projects (one git repository for
  each)? If so, how could I reference AuthenticationModule both in App1
  and App2?
- It is better to have a single git repository with both apps and the authentication module (3 solutions)?

Comment: in your specific example, they are two different sets of users and will not need a common auth module, you may be looking into two apps accessing the same JWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of "How your app" should be architected go well beyond what could or should be answered on StackOverflow. However I will give you some general information on working with Prism Modularity that I believe will help.

The scenario you laid out where you have as an example the Uber Passenger app and the Uber Driver app, each of which use the same user Authentication flow is a fantastic use case for having a common Authentication Module that your organization is able to reuse across apps.

How you choose to implement that Module again goes beyond the scope of what can/should be answered here. A possible way of handling this is to include a custom event like:

```
public class UserAuthenticatedEvent : PubSubEvent<string> { }
```

From a high level your code might look something like this:

```
public class LoginPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator { get; }
    private IAuthService _authService { get; }

    public LoginPageViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IAuthService authService)
    {
        _authService = authService;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    private string _userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get => _userName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set => SetProperty(ref _password, value);
    }

    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand { get; }

    private async void OnLoginCommandExecuted()
    {
        var jwt = await _authService.LoginAsync(UserName, Password);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UserAuthenticatedEvent>().Publish(jwt);
    }
}

public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        var ea = Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        ea.GetEvent<UserAuthenticatedEvent>().Subscribe(OnUserAuthencticated);
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<AuthenticationModule>();
    }

    private async void OnUserAuthencticated(string jwt)
    {
        // store jwt for use
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage");
    }
}
```

This allows your users to have a common login flow, while your app controls what happens and how that jwt gets stored for reuse. This could of course be further abstracted out... Remember in the scenario that you presented your both Drivers and Passengers would have a User Profile section and Settings which may be possible to abstract out into modules... Regardless of whether a Module can be reused across apps, Modules are also great at putting the Code into a Silo generally making it easier to test and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Explained a lot :)